# How to create file in partially known folder name using batch file

Tags: shell, batch-file, command

I want to create a 0 byte file names `dblank` in a specific directory `C:\Users\myUser\*.data\`.

```
echo. 2>"C:\Users\myUser\*.data\dblank.txt"
```

The * sign in the above command refers to any letters or numbers. I do not know. How can I refer to any letters or numbers in my batch code?

Comment: Is this a unixoid/Linux environment or some MS-Windows flavour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /ad C:\Users\myUser\*.data') do echo. 2>"%%f\dblank.txt"
```

**EDIT**
Filter results:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /ad C:\Users\myUser\*.data^|findstr /r "\\[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.data$"') do (
  echo. 2>"%%f\dblank.txt"
)
```

Comment: I do not get what you wrote. My script is working file if I specified the folder name instead of *. How can I tell my script that the * can be any letters of numbers? i.e. to folder name might be 12aa.data, 12bb.data, etc. I do not get why you make a for loop?

Comment: @user2192774 - this will find directory name.If you want you can filter the results with `findstr`

Comment: your second answers worked. the first does not create any file. I created the following directory: C:/testing/a54.data. I wrote your command as: `for /f %%f in ('dir C:\testing\*.data') do set "dirn=%%~dpfnsf"
echo. 2>"%dirn%\dblank.txt"` but no file has been created.

Comment: Now both works. I do not understand why I have to do it in for loop? Isn't there any sign in the batch code I can refer to any number or letter? The loop seems will make it less efficient. I assume there should be a sign such as % to refer to any letter or number?

Comment: @user2192774 the `FOR /f` will allow to process the output of a command.In your case `DIR` command - as you do not know the directory name `DIR` will find it.And you need it because redirection does not support wildcards.

Comment: If everything is OK you can accept the answer.If you need further help just ask.

Comment: Your regular expression permits characters like ! and $ so maybe this will filter only alphanumerics: `findstr /r "^[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.data"` but findstr does some strange things with regular expressions.

Comment: @foxidrive - regex fixed.10x

Comment: `echo \1aZa|findstr /r /e "\\[1-9]*[a-z]*[A-Z]*[1-9]*"` fails and so will terms with 0 (zero)

Comment: I altered your answers regexp and made solution 1 process all folders, also simplifying the folder path terms.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
setlocal enableextensions
for /D %%i in (C:\Users\myUsers\*.data) do copy nul "%%~i\dblank.txt"
endlocal
```

You can omit setlocal/endlocal if command extensions are already enabled (`cmd /E:on`).
This works on every existing `*.data` folder, if any.